# Allowing my webpage to display properly on arvixe using Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, master-pages, web-hosting

So, I have a complicated website built, (well maybe not as complicated as most), but anyhow, the basic principal is that I am using a Master Page, a stylesheet, and 4 content pages in my website.

I built it using Visual Studio 2013 and checked to make sure my website works on localhost. It does.

Now when I go to publish my website on Arvixe, I get 404 error. (meaning the file or directory is not found)

After doing some testing with file placement on a much simpler website, I found out that indeed the issue is with my Master Page. Because if I make a standard default.aspx that says hello world, then I take that and publish it to arvixe, everything works perfectly. But if I make a website that uses a MasterPage.master with the content page as  default.aspx, then nothing works and I get the 404 error.

All my files are placed under root on arvixe. Anyway, maybe im overlooking something very simple, or I have something weirdly wrong here.

just for clarification, here are the files I have on the arvixe server for the simple hello world website I made.....

```
Default.aspx
Default.aspx.cs
MasterPage.master
MasterPage.master.cs
Web.config
```

Any help is appreciated, and I will post code at any request. Thank you.